# Serializing printed documents

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone know of a way to print serial numbers from applications such as Microsoft Word within a single document? If not, is there a program or document format that would allow successive serial numbers to be printed in order to track worksheets/forms? I am trying to track every printed copy of a microsoft word document.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of would be to create an Excel sheet containing sequential numbers (one per row) and then use a mail-merge in Word to insert the numbers in to the document as it prints. You could put in this spreadsheet the person that each copy goes to, so it serves as your distribution record too.

Comment: +1 That's exactly how I used to do it in a previous job.